# Change tabBar badge when an app is in background mode (swift ios)

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I know that if I register `UIApplicationDelegate` in `UNUserNotificationCenter` and an app in foreground mode I will change `TabBarItem.badgeValue` easily. I only need to insert a piece of code in `func userNotificationCenter(...)`

But how to do the same thing when an app is in background mode? (like WhatsApp does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer...you don't. UI changes must be on the main thread. Instead, I would suggest you register for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification in `NotificationCenter` and update the badge value there.

(I use `UserDefaults` in the code below out of convenience and just for example. I might recommend using another method of storage based on how you're storing state in your app.)

Code while in background:

```
let badgeValue = 100
UserDefaults.standard.set(badgeValue, forKey: "badgeValue")
```

In your view controller:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //set it here for when view controller is loaded
        let badgeValue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "badgeValue")
        self.tabBarItem.badgeValue = badgeValue

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (notification) in
            //set it here for when you come back from the background
            let badgeValue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "badgeValue")
            self?.tabBarItem.badgeValue = badgeValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am going to try that out

Comment: @Jake - So I have added `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` as you mentioned in `application(...didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...)`. in `using` block I have added `self.window?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers.first?.tabBarItem.badgeValue = "100"` But In some reason it immediately changed without being connected to notification delivery. Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: #1 - I would put that code in your view controller, not your application delegate. #2 - that block is called every time the app becomes active, so store the value somewhere while you’re in the background and then set the badge to that value in the notification block. I’ll update my answer to reflect a little more detail

Comment: @Jake - Thank you a lot. It is really working! I put you code into `UIViewController.viewWillDisappear` and it has already shown me a badge

Comment: @Alex - I would not recommend putting the notification code in `viewWillDisappear` since that can be called multiple times. You'll possibly end up registering that block over and over again. `viewDidLoad` is the best place to register for the notification. I've updated my code to reflect that.

Comment: @Jake - It is true. put it in `onViewDidLoad` is much more right.